# How do I use gcc builtin __sync_bool_compare_and_swap in g++ on MacOSX?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, built-in

I have some code that uses:

```
__sync_bool_compare_and_swap
```

it compiles fine on Linux.

But when I try to compile it on MacOSX in g++, I get:

```
error: ‘__sync_bool_compare_and_swap’ was not declared in this scope
```

How do I fix this? (This is Mac OSX 10.5.8, so it's intel .. .and should have this instruction).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't find it, you can use OSCompareAndSwap() on Mac.

But it would be nice to have cross-platform code, wouldn't it.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the command line option

```
-march=i686
```

to the linker.

Answer (score 2):

if gcc --version doesn't show gcc 4.1 or newer then you don't have the instruction.

Xcode 3 (which is what's on Leopard) ships with gcc 4.2, but the default compiler is 4.0, which doesn't have the instruction

I just tested it on snow leopard, and the default gcc is 4.2.1, where it works.

Please see the note: [Setting GCC 4.2 as the default compiler on Mac OS X Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165361/setting-gcc-4-2-as-the-default-compiler-on-mac-os-x-leopard)

Answer (score 1):

What versions of GCC are you using?  (On both platforms).  This is a relatively recent addition to GCC.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, your box doesn't have the library you used on Linux that uses that function.

(The function wraps the instruction)

Answer (score 0):

OSAtomicAdd32 in libkern/OSAtomic.h

Answer (score -2):

the symbol __sync_bool_compare_and_swap is included in the toolchain(gcc/g++, and other compilers), and related with the version.

sometimes, you will find it, like this:
./arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/lib/gcc/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/plugin/include/sync-builtins.def:       "__sync_bool_compare_and_swap",
./arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/lib/gcc/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/plugin/include/sync-builtins.def:       "__sync_bool_compare_and_swap_1",
./arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/lib/gcc/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/plugin/include/sync-builtins.def:       "__sync_bool_compare_and_swap_2",
./arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/lib/gcc/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/plugin/include/sync-builtins.def:       "__sync_bool_compare_and_swap_4",
./arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/lib/gcc/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/plugin/include/sync-builtins.def:       "__sync_bool_compare_and_swap_8",
./arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/lib/gcc/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/plugin/include/sync-builtins.def:       "__sync_bool_compare_and_swap_16",