# using Pygsl with GCC 4.0 in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gsl, pygsl

I am trying to install pygsl using latest version of GCC, i.e.:

```
$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5659)
```

I get the error:

```
$ sudo python setup.py build
numpy
Building testing ufuncs!
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'errno' extension
C compiler: gcc-4.0 -arch ppc -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3

compile options: '-DSWIG_COBJECT_TYPES=1 -DGSL_RANGE_CHECK=1 -DDEBUG=1 -DNUMERIC=0 -DPYGSL_GSL_MAJOR_VERSION=1 -DPYGSL_GSL_MINOR_VERSION=9 -UNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -IInclude -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy-2.0.0.dev-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c'
gcc-4.0: src/init/errorno.c
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:4,
   from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:85,
                 from src/init/errorno.c:5:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:4,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:85,
                 from src/init/errorno.c:5:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//ccMNNq87.out
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:4,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:85,
                 from src/init/errorno.c:5:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:4,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:85,
                 from src/init/errorno.c:5:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//ccMNNq87.out
error: Command "gcc-4.0 -arch ppc -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -DSWIG_COBJECT_TYPES=1 -DGSL_RANGE_CHECK=1 -DDEBUG=1 -DNUMERIC=0 -DPYGSL_GSL_MAJOR_VERSION=1 -DPYGSL_GSL_MINOR_VERSION=9 -UNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -IInclude -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy-2.0.0.dev-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c src/init/errorno.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/src/init/errorno.o" failed with exit status 1
```

Any idea what might be causing this?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although gcc-4.2 is installed, you see that the build is using gcc-4.0 -- confusing.
Where's the "gcc-4.0" coming from ? Maybe the `setup.py`,
or `~/.pydistutils.cfg`, or `export CC-gcc-4.0` or ... just guessing, I don't have pygsl.
Can you get gcc-4.0 out of the way, as described in
SO [setting-gcc-4-2-as-the-default-compiler-on-mac-os-x-leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165361/setting-gcc-4-2-as-the-default-compiler-on-mac-os-x-leopard) ?