# How to change system default compiler in xcode 4?

Tags: compiler-construction, xcode4

I am editing projects on different machines, where only some have the GCC 4.2 (Plausible Blocks) installed, so I need to switch the compiler each time. (I need Plblocks on those machines to work with Blocks for older devices)

In the Build Settings I can choose an entry called "System Default", which is actually pointing to LLVM GCC 4.2, so my idea was to change this value. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Does the following question help?

[Setting GCC 4.2 as the default compiler on Mac OS X Leopard][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165361/setting-gcc-4-2-as-the-default-compiler-on-mac-os-x-leopard