# Ruby 1.9.3-p0 and RSpec causes frequent segmentation faults

Tags: segmentation-fault, rspec2, ruby-1.9.3

Is it just me, or has Ruby 1.9.3 introduced frequent segmentation faults when running RSpec?

Since upgrading to 1.9.3, I find startup time is noticeably quicker, however I get segmentation faults when running RSpec around 50% of the time.

The output that I am getting from Ruby is at http://pastebin.com/89YmpzaJ
and my Gemfile is at http://pastebin.com/L6r73Max

Does anyone know what could be causing this?  I am seeing this problem on both my CI server and my local development machine.

Comment: I have add segmentation faults trying to use rails 3.1 with ruby 1.8.7 that went away when I made sure rails used 1.9.2+  Don't know if that helps (so not an answer) but I thought I would mention it.  Sometimes when you have multiple ruby versions the wrong one gets picked too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There appears to be a problem with pry-doc/yard that can cause segfaults in yard. The best workaround I know of is to simply not use pry-doc. Pry-rails depends on pry-doc as a convenience, so in addition to removing pry-doc from your Gemfile, you will need modify pry-rails to remove its dependency on pry-doc.

(I've already forked pry-rails to do that: https://github.com/chrisfarber/pry-rails.)

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Not been using pry-doc for a few days now and since not had any issues.

Comment: BTW. Chris, have you raised a ticket with Pry-rails?  If not, I will raise one so that they are aware of the issue.

Comment: Good idea, Matt. I've posted an issue on its github page.

Answer (score 1):

the problem doesn't lie with ruby 1.9.3 but with your compiler, i guess you're on mac os x lio n and use Xcode 4.2? the new default compiler (llvm) somehow introduces a bug, which causes the continuation check in yard to cause a seg fault. as far as i remember, it should work, if you compile it with gcc 4.2

i think, this should do it

```
CC=gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3
```

Comment: Indeed I am using Mac OS X Lion, and XCode 4.2  How can I get rvm to compile using GCC instead of Xcode?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately made no difference.

Comment: There's a good post over here for setting your default compiler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165361/setting-gcc-4-2-as-the-default-compiler-on-mac-os-x-leopard

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after updating pry-doc to version 0.4.2, rspec runs all the time with out "segmentation faults"