# installing python packages StarCluster and pycrypto

Tags: python, pycrypto

Hi I am very new to python...so please forgive me if this is a silly question...

Having installed python 2.7.3 i wanted to install the package `StarCluster` which i tried doing via the command:

```
$ sudo easy_install StarCluster
```

but this led to errors when installing the dependent package `pycrypto` so tried separately to install that by using the command:

```
$ easy_install pycrypto
```

but get the following error message....Am I missing something that I need to do?

```
Searching for pycrypto
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycrypto/
Reading http://pycrypto.sourceforge.net
Reading http://www.pycrypto.org/
Reading http://www.amk.ca/python/code/crypto
Best match: pycrypto 2.6
Downloading http://ftp.dlitz.net/pub/dlitz/crypto/pycrypto/pycrypto-2.6.tar.gz
Processing pycrypto-2.6.tar.gz
Running pycrypto-2.6/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/N3/N3c0k2wGFciTmmsVNCCRE++++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-udIVh6/pycrypto-2.6/egg-dist-tmp-K6hQbK
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
src/MD2.c:147: fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe
compilation terminated.
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/N3/N3c0k2wGFciTmmsVNCCRE++++TI/-Tmp-//ccyyE9rh.out (No such file or directory)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

thanks

HLM

Comment: It looks like you're on OSX. Do you know if you have XCode installed? The out of the box OS X doesn't have a lot of the compilers and other installer goodness.

Comment: I do have XCode installed but its Version 4.0.2 do I need a newer version?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165361/setting-gcc-4-2-as-the-default-compiler-on-mac-os-x-leopard) to use 4.2 instead of 4.1 as the version of gcc.

---

Try his:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

`pip` is a python package manager: pip=pip installs packages. Then,

```
sudo pip install StarCluster
```

Then you can start python and import starcluster:

```
python
import starcluster
```

You can do the same with `pycrypto`:

```
sudo pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: i was assuming linux... whoops

Comment: it looks like a problem with `gcc 4.2`

Comment: yeh i installed pip anyway...but got the same error message i thinky ou are right with regard to the problem with `gcc 4.2` how is that fixed?

Comment: I would try updating xcode - that's the easiest way I know of.