# Gem installation ruby-audio-1.6.1 error(using Mac OS 10.9 / homebrew)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, audio, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried other tips but didn't work. (see link below please)
ex.
[Gem installation ruby-audio failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615596/gem-installation-ruby-audio-failing)
[ruby-audio 1.6.1 install error (with installed Libsndfile 1.0.25)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919640/ruby-audio-1-6-1-install-error-with-installed-libsndfile-1-0-25)

I want some feedback on this.

---

```
$ gem install ruby-audio<br>
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...<br>
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-audio:<br>
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.<br>

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
<br>
**checking for sndfile.h in /opt/local/include,/usr/local/include,C:/Program Files (x86)/Mega-Nerd/libsndfile/include,C:/Program Files/Mega-Nerd/libsndfile/include... yes<br>
checking for sf_open() in -lsndfile-1... no<br>
checking for sf_open() in -lsndfile... no<br>**<br>
*** extconf.rb failed ***<br>
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.<br>
<br>
Provided configuration options:<br>
    --with-opt-dir<br>
    --without-opt-dir<br>
    --with-opt-include<br>
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include<br>
    --with-opt-lib<br>
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib<br>
    --with-make-prog<br>
    --without-make-prog<br>
    --srcdir=.<br>
    --curdir<br>
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby<br>
    --with-sndfile-dir<br>
    --without-sndfile-dir<br>
    --with-sndfile-include<br>
    --without-sndfile-include=${sndfile-dir}/include<br>
    --with-sndfile-lib<br>
    --without-sndfile-lib=${sndfile-dir}/<br>
    --with-sndfile-1lib<br>
    --without-sndfile-1lib<br>
    --with-sndfilelib<br>
    --without-sndfilelib<br><br>
**extconf.rb:21:in `<main>':   Can't find libsndfile (http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) (RuntimeError)**<br>
<br>
  Try passing --with-sndfile-dir or --with-sndfile-lib and --with-sndfile-include<br>
  options to extconf. If there are spaces in the path on windows, it may not work.<br>
<br>
<br>
Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-audio-1.6.1 for inspection.<br>
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-audio-1.6.1/ext/rubyaudio_ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Did you install libsndfile?

Comment: Yes,
$ brew install libsndfile
Warning: libsndfile-1.0.25 already installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to install libsndfile as a universal library - by default it doesn't compile a 32-bit slice, which is required for compatibility with the system ruby.

```
brew uninstall libsndfile
brew install libsndfile --universal
sudo gem install ruby-audio
```

Comment: I tried the steps you mentioned and it worked!!!
Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

## For ubuntu (Ubuntu 18.04)

sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-get install -y libsndfile-dev